# Changed behaviour of LdToken for generic methods in .Net 4?

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-4.0, reflection.emit

Given a MethodInfo instance that identifies an open generic method of a non-generic class, consider the following pseudocode:

```
class Foo { void FooMethod<T>() {} }

public static void PrintMethodInfo(RuntimeMethodHandle methodHandle)
{
    var mi = (MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(methodHandle);
    Console.WriteLine("Method: "+mi.ToString());
}

var methodInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("FooMethod");
```

Generate a method "void GeneratedMethod<T>()" containing this code in the body:

```
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, methodInfo);
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodInfoPrintMethodInfo);
```

Calling GeneratedMethod<int>(), the output on .Net 3.5 will be:

```
Method: System.Object Method[Int32]()
```

While on .Net 4.0 it will be:

```
Method: System.Object Method[T]()
```

So it appears that in .Net 2.0/3.5, the generated IL for the ldtoken will contain a metadata token that identifies the generic FooMethod<> instantiated with the type argument given when GeneratedMethod<T> was called.

In .Net 4.0, however, the ldtoken will contain metadata that identifies the open generic type.

I'm having trouble finding documentation that support what's happening in the .Net 3.5 case (and indeed, it should fail completely if the generated method isn't itself generic) - the .Net 4 behaviour seems more logical. I can't find any documentation of the change either. Is this a bug in the earlier version that has now been fixed?

Comment: What do you mean, “the type argument given when GeneratedMethod was called”? Are you saying that you're the `GeneratedMethod` you're generating is generic and that you're calling it with `int` as a type argument?

Comment: @svick Yes, that's correct. I've edited so that the formatter doesn't swallow the generic parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you disassemble the generated code, you can see that in .NET 3.5, the `ldtoken` instruction in connection to the open generic method is emitted as follows:

```
.method public static void  GeneratedMethod<T>() cil managed
{
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  ldtoken    method instance void [ConsoleApplication16]ConsoleApplication16.Program/Foo::FooMethod<!!0>()
  IL_0005:  call       void [ConsoleApplication16]ConsoleApplication16.Program::PrintMethodInfo(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeMethodHandle)
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method TestType::GeneratedMethod
```

The syntax `!!0` is a reference to the type parameter of the surrounding method (`GeneratedMethod`), so the `Foo` method is loaded instantiated with the `T` belonging to `GeneratedMethod<T>`. (In fact, this is the same IL as would be emitted for `IL.Emit (OpCodes.Ldtoken, methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod (<typeParameterOfGeneratedMethod>))`.) This `!!0` reference is emitted even when `GeneratedMethod` is not generic at all - the resulting program is then no longer verifiable (and, when executed, results in a BadImageFormatException).

This is clearly a bug, and in .NET 4, this seems to be fixed, as the (disassembled) emitted code now looks like this:

```
.method public static void  GeneratedMethod<T>() cil managed
{
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  ldtoken    method instance void [ConsoleApplication16]ConsoleApplication16.Program/Foo::FooMethod<[1]>()
  IL_0005:  call       void [ConsoleApplication16]ConsoleApplication16.Program::PrintMethodInfo(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeMethodHandle)
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method TestType::GeneratedMethod
```

As you can see, the signature now refers to the uninstantiated `FooMethod` (in IL assembly, this is denoted as `FooMethod[1]`).

So yes, this looks like a bug in .NET 3.5 that was fixed with .NET 4. However, it doesn't seem to be a change in the semantics of `ldtoken`; it was just that Reflection.Emit didn't emit references to open generic methods correctly. I suspect it's also connected to [the fact that IL assembler didn't even have a syntax to denote open generic methods in the past](http://www.mail-archive.com/advanced-dotnet@discuss.develop.com/msg12626.html).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I'm not the only one seeing issues here. Luckily, in my case it turned out that the application code was actually cheating while using Reflection.Emit(), and making it more stringent made the code work the same on both 3.5 and 4.0.